# TTP (Nexus) times for parents vs. kids

Tags: usa, nexus

I recently registered my family for the Nexus program - me, my wife (registered herself), and our two kids (I registered both).  This was back in late August. The delay for conditional approval at the time was about 36 business days, from what I remember according to their website - so expecting to hear back from them in early to mid october.

I got my kids' conditional approvals Sept 28 and Oct 1.  However, my wife and I still haven't heard back on ours. There's no change in our status - we haven't been *declined*, just not yet conditional approval.  I've logged into each account to verify that I just didn't miss an email or something.

Is it common for adults to take significantly longer than children?

I received conditional approval a few weeks later, in early Decmeber. I never found out why it was that myself and my wife took so much longer than my sons' applications, and would still love to know.

Comment: As a followup note to my own question: I received conditional approval a few weeks later, in early Decmeber.  I never found out why it was that myself and my wife took so much longer than my sons' applications, and would still love to know.  (I finally got the interview in september this year - after trying in January but hitting the gov't shutdown... sigh.)

Comment: Just to add a clarification, since Mark generously bountied this:  I'm asking whether it is normal for kids to take less time than adults, not what the normal waiting time is.

Comment: I can't substantiate this at all, thus posting as a comment, but it sort of makes sense, since kids are less likely to have much information to review. I assume they review background checks, previous address, etc, where kids likely have had little to no information returned on those items, compared to adults, who are more likely to have a wealth of data come back.

Comment: I'd be perfectly happy to accept that as an answer @Midavalo - as evidence it's not a guarantee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I only have anecdotal evidence, based on my own experience and what I've been told while waiting on our SENTRI applications to be processed.

My kids took 2 or 3 weeks *longer* to receive conditional approval.

I emailed CBP several times while waiting (our SENTRI took over 12 months before Conditional Approval given), and all they'd say is that while it says PENDING then it's still in process and you just have to wait.

The Government shutdown had a HUGE impact on applications, and I have my theories on how they are trying to overcome that backlog.

Comment: Thanks for the anecdote, which seems to be as good as we have for now!  Sorry the shutdown slowed things down for you.